# How to change date time format in angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: datetime, angular7, date-format, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am new to angular, not able to change date time format in my calendar module.  I am using `angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker`. Basic config as below

```
 <dl-date-time-picker 
    maxView="day" 
    minView="day" 
    startView="day" 
    minuteStep="5" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedDate">
 </dl-date-time-picker>
```

Want to change from `(EEEE, MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a zzzz)` format to `(yyyy/mm/dd)` format

Comment: try better this one https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api
it's better supported and most likely have more rich functionality

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to change for format of the date displayed in an input box - use https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/directives/DlDateTimeInputDirective.html